# Angular Material is not responsive in Chrome debug (device) mode

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, responsive-design, angular-material

I've encountered an odd problem. 
Inside my html file I've defined two attributes:

1. Hide me on small devices
2. Hide me on larder then small devices

When I'm resizing the window the attributes are doing they work. But, when I'm entering into device debug mode (e.g. iPhone 5) nothing happens. When I'm trying to resize the window (in responsive mode, not iPhone 5) the  are zooming out and not hidden while I'm reaching the hide-xs breakpoint.

Beside this issue, ngMaterial working fine. It arranges layouts like it should and I didn't encountered any other problems.

PS
I'm using Bower package manager to maintain the dependencies. First I thought it may be somehow related to the ngMaterial version. But it probably not.

[Here is the site which I'm developing.](https://dev.creativeit.co/CRE.PaymentsPortal/#/) You can play with it's log-in page to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Here is what [Pajn](https://github.com/Pajn) wrote on Github forum:

> Include a viewport-meta-tag like

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

> to tell the brower that your site is
>   responsive and should be rendered using correct CSS pixel scaling.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! That saved me a bit of time :)